# How do you find the potential size of a file after a grep/cut in Bash?

Tags: bash, cut

Let's say you have a very large file with 30 columns, of differing sizes, and you cut out 6 of them. Can you determine the size of the new file that would actually have those 6 columns?

Comment: Not really; if you know that all the columns have roughly the same "width" and don't vary significantly from row to row, you can estimate that the new file is 20% of the size of the orginal, having discarded 80% of the roughly equal-sized "cells".

Comment: @chepner You don't need to estimate. You can use `wc -c` as I suggested in the answer.

Comment: `wc -c` isn't finding the *potential* size, it's calculating the *actual* size after the fact. I assumed the question was about predicting the file size without actually generating it.

Comment: @chepner Yes, it calculates the actual size. I assumed OP is using grep/cut and wants to know the size. That's how I understand it.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wc:

```
grep pattern file | wc -c
```

It will return number of bytes.